# How to migrate code from RTC to TFS VC with History

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

My team was Plan to migrate from RTC to the TFS VC scm. I haven't found a lot of info about migrating out of RTC into TFVC in general.
What will be the best way to migrate our source code and change history from RTC to TFVC?

Comment: What' the RTC you are talking about, a git 3rd-party tool? Did you just want to migrate from GIT version control to TFVC version control in TFS?

Comment: Here IBM RTC version control to TFVC migration code ....please suggest me whether it is possible to git? and how?

Comment: Hi sandy, did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for RTC (even if it seems that there is a `rtc2git` tool) but there is not a lot of tools to migrate to TFVC (The api is not very good for importing history!).

Your only chance is to migrate to git and then use `git-tf` to migrate to TFVC (but forget about migrating branches, you will only able to migrate the trunk) and it will be very slow....

Nowadays, git is the way to go (even Microsoft is migrating entirely to it) and I highly advise you to migrate to TFS-git instead...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RTC(Rational Team Concert).

One thing is clear, there are no tools for use to directly migrate artifacts and Projects from RTC and RQM to TFS. You could submit a user voice on IBM's related forums.

Do not know if there is an official way to migrate from RTC to GIT. However you could use [rtc2git](https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git)

> A tool made for migrating code and code-history from an existing RTC
>   SCM repository into a Git repository It uses the CLI of RTC to gather
>   the required informations.

After migrate to GIT, you could use the [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) tool which is a two-way bridge between Team Foundation Version Control and Git, and can be used to perform a migration.

Answer (score 0):

RTC now even supports a Git backend. Good way to sync common (open source) code with your internal code libraries. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.4/com.ibm.team.connector.cq.doc/topics/c_integ_git.html